# Can't clone git repository with jenkins (permission denied)

Tags: git, ssh, permissions, key

I'm having a hard time with Jenkins and git. I had Jenkins installed on a virtual machine in the office and was able to include a git repository in my project and do a syntax check, etc. Today I came back, restarted the virtual computer and can't simply build the project. It sais: Permission denied because of ym public key. Created a new project with same repository, still can't. Created a new virtual machine the same way, still can't. All my git repositories are saying the exact same, that my public key is denied. However when I ssh into the server and try to git clone a repository it works like a charm.

I've tried to add the SSH keypair to Jenkins every possible way, but all the times I got the pubkey error. Why? I use gitolite server but haven't changed anything from Friday to tomorrow.... What gives?

Comment: Is Jenkins running as the user `jenkins`? Did you try logging in as `jenkins` and running `git clone`? Did you put the private key in `/home/jenkins/.ssh/id_rsa`?

Comment: No, I did not try to git clone as jenkins user. Gonna try it right now. I've put my keys into my own home folder plus I also tried to add the certificate directly when jenkins asks for a key. Didn't help.

Comment: Tried to clone the git with jenkins user and it worked like a charm. It requested my passphrase OFC, but after giving it, to him, there was no problem. The error message still exists on the WebGUI.

Comment: `It requested my passphrase OFC` It should not need a passphrase if it is authenticating with an SSH key. That is your problem. Make sure you are using the ssh protocol (not https) and you have a key setup to work without a passphrase for the jenkins user.

Comment: Yes, I was aware of that and that was the 1st thing I've set up when created new creditentals in Jenkins. However as you can read below creating a new key without passphrase works.

Answer (score 0):

Made a new keypair for jenkins user, this time with no password. Somewhy this works. Can anybody tell me why? I though that this issue have been resolved already.